# Header file not found while using soong build Android.bp in AOSP

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, android-source, android-soong

I am trying to build my HAL implementation and service using Android.bp Soong build. Even though the build process is successful with Android.mk, after converting this Android.mk file into Android.bp, the build process is failed with the error as header file not found.

```
hardware/interfaces/hvuleds/2.0/default/Hvuleds.h:24:10: fatal error: 'linux/msm_mdp.h' file not found
#include <linux/msm_mdp.h>
```

This is content of Android.mk file with success and my HAL performs well on real device:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE_RELATIVE_PATH := hw
LOCAL_PROPRIETARY_MODULE := true

LOCAL_MODULE := android.hardware.hvuleds@2.0-service
LOCAL_INIT_RC := android.hardware.hvuleds@2.0-service.rc
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
    service.cpp \

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := \
    libcutils \
    libdl \
    libbase \
    libutils \
    libhardware \
    libhidlbase \
    libhidltransport \
    android.hardware.hvuleds@2.0 \
    android.hardware.hvuleds@2.0-impl \

include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)


LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := android.hardware.hvuleds@2.0-impl
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Hvuleds.cpp

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := \
    libbase \
    liblog \
    libhidlbase \
    libhidltransport \
    libhardware \
    libutils \
    android.hardware.hvuleds@2.0 \

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And this is content of Android.bp file automatically converted from above Android.mk by using `androidmk` tool:

```
    relative_install_path: "hw",
    proprietary: true,

    name: "android.hardware.hvuleds@2.0-service",
    init_rc: ["android.hardware.hvuleds@2.0-service.rc"],
    srcs: ["service.cpp"],

    shared_libs: [
        "libcutils",
        "libdl",
        "libbase",
        "libutils",
        "libhardware",
        "libhidlbase",
        "libhidltransport",
        "android.hardware.hvuleds@2.0",
        "android.hardware.hvuleds@2.0-impl",
    ],

}


cc_library_shared {
    name: "android.hardware.hvuleds@2.0-impl",
    srcs: ["Hvuleds.cpp"],

    shared_libs: [
        "libbase",
        "liblog",
        "libhidlbase",
        "libhidltransport",
        "libhardware",
        "libutils",
        "android.hardware.hvuleds@2.0",
    ],

}
```

Can anyone help me and explain this error ?
Thanks !
Best regards!